# End of Game and restart button Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I've implemented a game in which, at the end of all lives, the game is over.
So I've to pause at this point the scene and then I've to implement the label Game Over (Done), the points and a button that allows to restart the game. At now, when the game is finished, I've got a overlay of the game over label and the new starting game ! I want to pause the game in a view with the game over and points.

This is my code:

```
-(void)gameOver:(int)value punteggio:(id)punti{
    if (value == 1) {
        // partita vinta
    } else if (value == 2) {
        if (life > 1) { // 1
            life = life - 1;
            for (CCSprite *spr in spriteLifeArray) {
                if (life == spr.tag) {
                    [self removeChild:spr cleanup:YES];
                }
            }
        } else { 
            //  partita persa
            Gameover = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"Game Over!" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:34];
            [Gameover setColor:ccc3(255, 1, 1)];
            Gameover.position = ccp(size.width / 2, size.height / 2);
            [self addChild:Gameover];
            //blinking
            id action1 = [CCBlink actionWithDuration:0.3 blinks:5];
            [Gameover runAction: action1];
            [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve? How can I make this button to restart the game in a paused scene? 
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved creating a Node, called GameOVer with a function restart. In the GameOver implementation I've writed a function to restart

```
-(void) restart {    
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[HelloWorldLayer node]];
}
```

and I've linked this function to a label in the GameOver Layer:

```
CCMenuItemLabel *back = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:label2  target:self selector:@selector(restart)];
```

Finally I've connected in the main layer, if `lives==0` this code

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[GameOver node]];
```

And all work properly! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

Create a simple CCMenu with a CCMenuItemLabel.

```
      CCMenuItemLabel *gameOver = [CCMenuItemLabel itemWithLabel:@"Game Over!" target:self selector:@selector(restart:)];
      CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:gameOver, nil];
      [self addChild:menu z:(Something bigger than all others so that it shows up on top)];
```

Then in your restart method:

```
    -(void) restart:(id)sender{
          menu.visible = NO;
          //code to restart your game;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You...something bigger means for example a background.png with the size of the screen? Can I send my code to you to show in detail how it works? Thank You for the help! :)

Comment: When  you add a child to self, z is the order on which the childs are drawn (ie child with z:0 is drawn behind child with z:5), so you want the z for you game over label to be bigger than all other so that it is drawn on top.

Comment: Thank You very much...is a very simple quiz game...how can I give you my code? :)

Comment: I've accepted it but please help me with this code because I'm a beginner with cocos2d and I've some trouble..can you help me please?

Comment: what specifically do you need help with?

Comment: when the lives go to 0, i want to set a black page (black for now), may be an hud o everything else with "Game Over", the score and a label to restart the game. There's a function that controls the number of life with a if cycle!

Comment: Done! :) Now I post the answer